# Google spreadsheet Query function parse error on 1 column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax, google-query-language, single-quotes

I have a query to fetch data from another sheet. One of the columns contains Yes/No in most rows. I have made the format of the column text but the query will not parse this column. If I omit the column it works fine.
QUERY(Summary!A1:CR1,"select A,B,CK,L,C,K,U,N,AB, etc,,,,,,,BY,,,,etc,,,")

error is Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "by" "BY "" at line 1, column 116. Was expecting one of: "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BY` needs to be backquoted:

```
=QUERY(Summary!A1:CR1,"select A,B,CK,L,C,K,U,N,AB,`BY`,BX")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I guessed it was to do with the query expecting a particular data type. It would be useful to know what the back tick does and why the other columns worked.

Comment: @mikeimp see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#reserved-words